# Unable to render html divs with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to generate several `divs` based off an array - but I'm unable to. I click a button, which is supposed to return the `divs` via mapping but it's returning anything.

```
class History extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    info: ""
  };
  this.generateDivs = this.generateDivs.bind(this);
}

async getCurrentHistory(address) {
  const info = await axios.get(`https://api3.tzscan.io/v2/bakings_history/${address}?number=10000`);
  return info.data[2];
}

async getHistory() {
  const info = await getCurrentHistory(
    "tz1hAYfexyzPGG6RhZZMpDvAHifubsbb6kgn"
  );
  this.setState({ info });
}

generateDivs() {
  const arr = this.state.info;
  const listItems = arr.map((cycles) => 
      <div class="box-1">
        Cycle: {cycles.cycle}
        Count: {cycles.count.count_all}
        Rewards: {cycles.reward}
      </div>
  );
  return (
    <div class="flex-container">
      { listItems }
    </div>
  )
}

componentWillMount() {
  this.getHistory();
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.generateDivs}>make divs</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @andymccullough I didn't include my `componentWillMount` in this piece of code which populates state.info with an array

Comment: Can you add that please

Comment: @andymccullough Updated

Comment: Did you re-type this code or copy/paste it in?  Aren't you missing the closing parenthesis `)` on your `array.map()` function call?

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually rendering the the divs just by invoking the `generateDivs` function, the JSX it is returning is not being used anywhere.

To get it to work you could do something like -

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.showDivs}>make divs</button>
      {this.state.isDisplayed && this.generateDivs()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

where `showDivs` would be a function to toggle the state property `isDisplayed` to true

The main point is that the JSX being returned in the `generateDivs` function will now be rendered out in the `render` function.  There is many ways to toggle the display, that is just one straight forward way